# Bootstrap 5 Form Inputs to Take the Rest of the Space

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-forms

In Bootstrap 5, I have a form displayed in a modal, inputs are preceded with icons. I want to make the inputs take the whole space after the icons (the rest of the purple zone as in the screenshot)

Any other suggestions to do the structure a better way without changing the final result is appreciated.

[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-p" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editpLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="changeppLabel">Edit my profile</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="px-3 pb-3">
                <form class="row" id="profile-edit" method="POST">
                    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-mars me-3" title="Male"></i> </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="" name="name" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="" value="Mohamed KADRI">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot me-3" title="City"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <select name="city" class="form-select" aria-label="">
                                
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-cake-candles me-3" title="Birthday"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="" name="birthdate" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="" value="1987-04-21">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-phone me-3" title="Phone"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="" name="phone" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="" value="21256607">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook me-3" title="Facebook"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="" name="facebook" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="" value="medkadri">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram me-3" title="Instagram"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="" name="instagram" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="" value="mohamed.kadri_">
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div style="justify-content: space-between;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" id="profile-edit-submit" class="btn btn-primary float-end">Update</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            <div id="edit-p" class="pt-3">
                <small></small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="justify-content: space-between;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add classes `d-flex flex-grow-1` to the second `col-auto`.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit-p">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="edit-p" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editpLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="changeppLabel">Edit my profile</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="px-3 pb-3">
          <form class="row" id="profile-edit" method="POST">
            <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
              <div class="col-auto">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-mars me-3" title="Male"></i> </div>
              <div class="col-auto d-flex flex-grow-1">
                <input type="" name="name" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="" value="Mohamed KADRI">
              </div>
              <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot me-3" title="City"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto d-flex flex-grow-1">
                <select name="city" class="form-select" aria-label="">

                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cake-candles me-3" title="Birthday"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto d-flex flex-grow-1">
                <input type="" name="birthdate" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="" value="1987-04-21">
              </div>
              <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-phone me-3" title="Phone"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto d-flex flex-grow-1">
                <input type="" name="phone" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="" value="21256607">
              </div>
              <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook me-3" title="Facebook"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto d-flex flex-grow-1">
                <input type="" name="facebook" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="" value="medkadri">
              </div>
              <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram me-3" title="Instagram"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto d-flex flex-grow-1">
                <input type="" name="instagram" class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="" value="mohamed.kadri_">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div style="justify-content: space-between;">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              <button type="submit" id="profile-edit-submit" class="btn btn-primary float-end">Update</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div id="edit-p" class="pt-3">
            <small></small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="justify-content: space-between;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```